# Why does vue generated js files not found by flask server and leaving a blank page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flask

back end codes here

```
app = Flask(__name__,
            static_folder = "../frontend/dist/static",
            template_folder = "../frontend/dist")
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# enable CORS
CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}})
```

vue app codes here

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <nav>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </nav>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

vue.config.js here

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? './frontend/dist/' : '',
}
```

while whatever the server or I manually paste the address in bar, the js file was not found

I've tried modified the vue.config.js by several ways such as changing the publicPath value, checking the project root path, it doesn't work at all